Loop VBA Microsoft Excel
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
If ActiveSheet.Range("AK4").Value = 0 Then
    CXBTN1.Value = False
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range("AK4").Value = "FALSE" Then
    CXBTN1.Value = False
Else
    CXBTN1.Value = True
End If

'CheckBox
If ActiveSheet.Range("AL4").Value = 0 Then
    CXBTN2.Value = False
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range("AL4").Value = "FALSE" Then
    CXBTN2.Value = False
Else
    CXBTN2.Value = True
End If
End Sub

Is there a way I can loop through this? I'm doing it manually. I can't seem to find the loop for this.

What do you mean by "doing it manually"? Doesn't the above code do what is should do? Try using UserForm_Initialize instead of UserForm_Activate, anyhow, but this will not be the solution... Do you mean that you show the form manually and need  to show it using a piece of code? Or what? If it works and it does not do what you need, are you sure that the active sheet is the one you want? Does it raise any error? Is CXBTN2 a button? If not (I supposed that looking to its name), what is it?

It doesnt seem to have any error. but doing it to 84 individual buttons will take too much long. and there are too many codes and a large margin of error.

Then, I cannot understand anything related to your real problem. Please, edit our question and better explain what you want. You need to supply the logic based on what to make the code more compact. I mean, if there are 84 such buttons and you need to use for the first one "Ak4, for the next one "AL4", for the following "AM4", "AN4" and so on it is something to be followed and put in place. Then, what do you try doing at a button using CXBTN1.Value = True?

Like this:
celladdrs = Array("AK4", "AL4") 'extend as needed
ctls= Array(CXBTN1, CXBTN2)
for i = 0 to 1
    addr = celladdrs(i)
    ' Use "Set" for object assignment!
    Set control = ctls(i)
    If ActiveSheet.Range(addr).Value = 0 Then
        control.Value = False
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range(addr).Value = "FALSE" Then
        control.Value = False
    Else
        control.Value = True
    End If
Next


Supposing that all buttons to be changed have their name continuously incremented from 1 to 85, please use the next way. It is not need to place anything in arrays. If you add a new button, it would be enough to change the maximum number to be incremented (85 to 86 and so on...):
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
  Dim i As Long, rngMatch As Range
  Const btPref As String = "CXBTN"
  Set rngMatch = Range("AK4")
  For i = 1 To 85 'use here the number of buttons
    If rngMatch.Offset(, i - 1).Value = 0 Or rngMatch.Offset(, i - 1).Value = "FALSE" Then
        Me.Controls(btPref & i).Value = False
    Else
        Me.Controls(btPref & i).Value = True
    End If
  Next i
End Sub

Not tested, but it should work as you need. Of course, if the button naming against columns incrementation respect the rule...
